# How to retrieve the value of a shadowed global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

Example:

```
var test = 'global value';

(function() {
    var test = 'local value';

    // how to get the 'global value' string
})();
```

Given the condition that the host environment is unknown, meaning that we cannot assume that the global object will be accessible via the `window` name. Also, the function is not allowed to receive any arguments!

Comment: Is this theoretical or you actually want to solve this in existing code?

Comment: Since it's theoretical, this means no one has written this code yet. it should be left that way :)

Comment: +1 this is a great JavaScript question, sadly don't see these too often here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The fix

```
var test = 'global value';

(function() {
    var test2 = 'local value';

    console.log(test);
})();
```

The real solution is to fix your code so your not shadowing global variables you care about.

### Eval work around

You can always use global eval, it's the most reliable.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rNtbN/)

```
var test = 'global value';

function runEval(str) {
  return eval(str);
}

(function() {
    var test = 'local value';

    console.log(runEval("test"));
})();
```

If you don't like defining a global eval you can use `Function` to do it indirectly

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rNtbN/9/)

```
var test = 'global value';

(function() {
    var test = 'local value';

    console.log(new Function ("return test;") () );
})();
```

### Miscellaneous hacks

The following works in non strict mode

```
(function () {
  var test = "shadowed";

  console.log(this !== undefined && this.test);
})();
```

And this hack works in broken implementations

```
(function() {
    var test = 'local value';

    try { delete test; } catch (e) { }

    console.log(test);
})();
```

Comment: For global `eval()` could you just do an *indirect call* to `eval()` ?

Comment: AFAIK spec states an indirect call to `eval()` will set its execution context as global code.

Comment: @alex yes you can, I used `Function` as an indirect call

Comment: You can do it with `globalThis` since ES2020. I posted a separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68524973/9150270), feel free to include it in your own one.

Answer (score 1):

What about relying on its `this` as the global object (no explicit reference to `window`).

```
console.log(this.test);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnEFE/).

You could also use an indirect call to `eval()` (`execScript()` is here for IE purposes, but feel free to ignore as you mentioned to not assume a browser).

```
console.log((window.execScript || eval)('test'));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfmXF/).

Comment: @Raynos: Yeah, but OP didn't list that as a requirement.

Comment: @alex Damn, I forgot...  Now I have to accept your answer `:)`

Comment: @imeVidas: Never a bad thing :D

Comment: @alex The shortest way to have global eval is: `(1,eval)('test')`

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally the big issue, if you want to do this in strict-mode code, is getting the global object. Thankfully there are some simple ways: `var global = (1,eval)("this");` (which doesn't work in every browser, as its behaviour is undefined in ES3, though defined in ES5) or  `var global = (new Function("return this"))();` (which does).

So, put that together with what else you need, you can have a function such as:

```
function getGlobal(name) {
  "use strict";
  var global = (new Function("return this"))();
  return global[name];
}
```

It'd probably be better to avoid the cost of creating a function each time, so something like the following would be better:

```
var getGlobal = (function() {
  "use strict";
  var global = (new Function("return this"))();
  return function(name) {
    return global[name];
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. A "cheeky" way to get past the "not allowed to receive any arguments" might be to use `call`:

```
var test = 'global value';

(function() {
    var test = 'local value';

    var globalTest = this.test;
}).call(this);
```

But if you can count on `this` being the global object when no `this` is explicitly specified, then `this.test` will work.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I meant inside the function. This is the case in most browser JavaScript implementations when *not* using `'use strict';`.

Comment: Yea, I forgot to add ES6 strict as a requirement `:/`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to memoize the global object:

```
var test = "global";
function called() {
    var test = "local";
    alert(arguments.callee.window.test); // alerts "global"
}
called.window = this;
called();
```

Comment: OP said not to make explicit mention to `window`. Also `callee` shouldn't really be used anymore.

Comment: @alex: But he's not actually using `window`... I agree about `callee` though, wasn't it removed in ES5? Or at least disallowed in strict?

Comment: @minitech: Yeah, but it could of been named `global`, considering the OP says *host environment is unknown*.

Comment: I used `arguments.callee` just to not write `called` again and have another place to edit if you want to change the function name. Just change the line to `alert(called.window.test);`.

Answer (score 0):

There is [globalThis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157864/what-is-globalthis-in-javascript-what-will-be-the-ideal-use-case-for-this) since ES2020, [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#browser_compatibility) by all modern browsers.

```
var test = 'global value';

(function() {
    var test = 'local value';

    console.log(globalThis.test); // 'global value'
})();
```